# Why does gdb on assembly program always start at the same address?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, memory-layout

I have created the most basic assembly file I can think of to figure out how `gdb` works in order to debug things. Here is my file:

```
.globl main
main:
    mov $6,     %eax
    ret
```

My question is why does the addresses on the right always start at `0x00000000004004ed` ? For example, what doesn't it start at `0` or `AAAA` or some other number? It seems whenever I start gdb it loads that. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

To run I did:

```
$ gcc mx.s -o mx && gdb mx
>>> b main
>>> r
```

Comment: Because `ld` chose that at link time, at the default address for the top of the text segment for a non-PIE executable.  Since it's position-dependent, the kernel's ELF program loader has no choice but to load it there.  `0` would be a terrible choice because it would make NULL-pointer dereference load this code instead of faulting.